# module installation takes too long to install which are in depends in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

can you please help me regarding module installation problem in odoo12.
i have created a custom module in which i have put these modules on depends.

here is my manifest depends.

```
depends': ['sale_management', 'purchase', 'account','stock','hr','hr_payroll','l10n_in'],
```

when i am installing module it generates this error after installation of some modules "hr, hr_payroll , account, etc." .[image]

after getting an error if i reload and press on install again then it installs my module perfectly and it works fine.

and if i install stock, sale_management, purchase manually first, then it does not generates any error and my module get install and works.

**thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because thread execution time exceeds `limit_time_real` defined in `odoo.conf` which is set to `120s`.

Odoo warns you only if `limit_time_real` is set and its value is lesser than the thread execution time.

Comment: thanks for the answer.but can you please tell me, how can i get rid of this situation?

Comment: Resetting `limit_time_real` to the default value (`None`) will avoid this warning.